# How to find $k$-dimensional affine subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Let $V$ be an affine space of dimension n over the finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$ of $q$ elements. How
many $k$-dimensional affine subspaces are there in $V$?

So this is a question I came across while studying about affine space.I had encountered similar question related to vector space where they asked to find $k$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over the finite field $\Bbb{F}_q$ of $q$ elements. I understood how it was found. So should I use the same methodologies or something else?

P.S. Affice space is something very new to me so if anyone can give a detail explanation of how to do or how to approach. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Every $k$-dimensional subspace gives rise to $q^{\dim V-k}$ affine spaces "parallel" to it, so one only needs to multiply the number of subspaces by that factor.

Comment: @GregMartin Hi! I do remember while solving for a k-dimensional subspace I got something like this $$ \frac{
    (q^n-1)(q^n-q) \dotsm (q^n-q^{k-1})
    }{
    (q^k-1)(q^k-q) \dotsm (q^k-q^{k-1})
    }
$$

Comment: @GregMartin I did not get how you got ${q^(dimV−k)}$